# Generating lines at an increment

Tags: java, swing

Given a line AB, how would I generate two lines perpendicular to AB such that they both divide it into thirds (or any other fraction, for that matter)?

I originally thought to find the length of AB by using the distance formula on points A and B and then drawing two lines at increments of 1/3 the length of AB on it, but that seems both inefficient and impractical if used many times at once.

Comment: This sounds like a mathematical construction, not a programming problem. If you are writing a program to do this, how do you represent lines and points?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "if used many times at once"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice When I say "lines and points," I literally mean lines and points, as in drawing a line in a JFrame and dividing it into thirds using two other lines.

Comment: In order to draw a line, you still have to represent it with data somehow in your code. Which leads me back to my original question.

Comment: My second question is probably more important, though.

Comment: "If used many times at once" refers to running the process multiple times simultaneously, like if one wanted to generate several of these such formations on one JFrame within one program.

Comment: Note that a single CPU can only perform one calculation at a time. The only way to do two calculations simultaneously is with multiple CPUs or cores and then you also need to write code especially forthe parallel computation using threads or multiple processes. I think this is probably more complex than what you actually mean by "multiple times simultaneously." Instead I think you mean is you have multiple lines which all need to be trisected. Or are you talking about trisecting the same line multiple times?

Comment: the former; that there are multiple lines to be trisected

Comment: There is not much you can do. You will need to calculate the necessary points for each line. However, once you calculate these, you can certainly store the results in a variable so that you do not need to repeat the calculation for the same line. Then the trade off is that you must use more memory to save processing speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems reasonable. You should probably not worry about efficiency concerns yet. When you decide to start worrying about it, then you should profile your code to measure the actual bottle necks rather than guessing where they may be.

Another approach to your problem is to represent a line as all points `C` which satisfy the equation

```
C = (1-t)*A + t*B
```

where `t` is a real number between 0 and 1 (inclusive).

Now you can easily calculate values of C that divide the line segment AB into thirds by setting `t` to 1/3 and 2/3 respectively.